# export function not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodemailer

I am using the nodemailer example function, which I then export into my index.ts; however, when I run my script it is not being called in index.ts file. The nodemailer function is called **sendEmail** Here is the `nodemailer/sendEmail.ts` file:

```
 import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
 import chalk from 'chalk';
 
 // async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
export async function sendEmail(to: string, text: string) {
    // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
    // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
    let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
    //DOES NOT APPEAR IN NODE CONSOLE
    console.log(chalk.red("testaccount", testAccount));
  
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
      port: 587,
      secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
        user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
        pass: testAccount.pass, // generated ethereal password
      },
    });
  
    // send mail with defined transport object
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
      to: to, // list of receivers
      subject: "Change Password", // Subject line
      text: text, // plain text body
      html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
    });
  
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  }
```

**Here is where I call it in the index.ts file:**

```
//import the exported function
import { sendEmail } from "./utils/sendEmail";
const main = async () => {
  console.log(chalk.bgRed.bold("TEST TEST")) // <- Prints to console
 sendEmail("testemail@gmail.com", "hello there"); // <- Does not print
  const orm = await MikroORM.init(mikroConfig); // <- Prints
  await orm.getMigrator().up(); 
  const app = express();
 //...... other config logic ......
};
main().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Could you try wrapping the content of the sendMail function in a try catch, I suspect a silent error here

Comment: The `sendEmail` function is **asynchronous** but when you call it, you do not wait for it to complete and therefore next instructions are executed.

In the `main` function, you first log `TEST TEST`, which prints. Then, you call `sendMail` but do not `await` it, therefore the next `MikroORM.init` prints.

My guess is that the `createTestAccount` function in `sendEmail` is taking some time to execute or is silently failing, that’s why you don’t see your log right away.

Comment: I see! So I wrapped it in a try catch block and now I see that the function has been properly executed. Thanks y'all!